# Background color won't change on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So, I have changed the view´s background color, sometimes by using the visual tool, other times using a image as a pattern for a UIColor. It all looks fine on device simulator, but when running on a device, all the backgrounds looks white.

It doesnt matter if I selected a solid color or used a image at the project bundle to color its background, they all stay white ONLY when running on the device. I even ran on retinal simulator, and it looked ok.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling whatever exists of the app on the device totally and then building it for the device from Xcode again?

Comment: Yes, I did. Ive tired many methods to change the BG color, no results.

Comment: Make sure you're loading the right view controller.  If it's for iPad, make sure you're using iPad simulator, and the same for iPhone.  Just thinking maybe you're editing one xib but seeing the other one when you run on the device.

Comment: No, is not that. I have only one target, one xib for each viewcontroller. Im running the simulations on the iphone simulator and the app on an iphone device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that once, after localizing my xibs. Tried many times (many days) to solve it, loading the images again and again, nothing worked. It made me crazy... should be an Xcode bug...
to save time, try to create another project, import the current one (I imported the code, class by class, and the images). It worked for me. no explanation to date!